# Typical time of execution for elementary functions

Tags: c++, performance, assembly, low-level

It is well-known that the processor instruction for multiplication takes several times more time than addition, division is even worse (UPD: which is not true any more, see below). What about more complex operations like exponent? How difficult are they?

**Motivation**. I am interested because it would help in algorithm design to estimate performance-critical parts of algorithms on early stage. Suppose I want to apply a set of filters to an image. One of them operates on 3×3 neighborhood of each pixel, sums them and takes atan. Another one sums more neighbouring pixels, but does not use complicated functions. Which one would execute longer?

So, ideally I want to have approximate relative times of elementary operations execution, like multiplication typically takes 5 times more time than addition, exponent is about 100 multiplications. Of course, it is a deal of orders of magnitude, not the exact values. I understand that it depends on the hardware and on the arguments, so let's say we measure average time (in some sense) for floating-point operations on modern x86/x64. For operations that are not implemented in hardware, I am interested in typical running time for C++ standard libraries.

Have you seen any sources when such thing was analyzed? Does this question makes sense at all? Or no rules of thumb like this could be applied in practice?

Comment: It would also be effected by locality of reference, cache miss and context switching. So it would be futile to anticipate and fix micro optimizations like what you are planning to do.

Comment: The two filters you describe seem to do different things. Is it really meaningful to compare their performance directly?

Comment: Also note that cmath functions are part of the library, that means their speed is depending at least on the quality of your implementation, and also possibly on the compiler settings you use.

Comment: *"It is well-known that processor instruction for multiplication takes several times more time than addition"* - this was true once, but most modern CPUs now have the same throughput for multiplication and addition. So old skool optimisations where adds are traded for multiplies are not always valid these days.

Comment: @parapura normally, yes, thanks for the point! But in my case with the images all the neighborhood is likely to be cached, and references are local, since code is small (if I understand correctly what you mean by locality of reference). Note also that each operation is performed in a cycle, so statistically it may be fruitful. Also, I'd like to know that just out of interest.

Comment: @R. Martinho, I want to detect the most computationally demanding element to check if it is efficient enough, and if not I won't implement the others.

Comment: @Paul Okay, and what about the things like exponent where lookup tables and Taylor expansion are used? How efficient are they now?

Comment: There's no simple answer - you have to remember that technology changes rapidly and what is true at some point may not be true a year or two later, e.g. lookup tables do not work well with parallel architectures such as SIMD and GPGPU, or even with modern general purpose CPUs if table accesses result in cache misses.

Comment: @overrider: Unless you image is an icon it is unlikely to be all cached. It will be loaded into cache and discarded from cache as required very quickly. It will be more important how you design the overall algorithm for applying the filter (to make sure the correct part of the image is in the cache) than how you define you filter to work.

Comment: you can implement a multiply or an add in a single clock cycle, its a no brainer (takes a lot of gates, yes) and has been a single clock thing for a long time (on anything you are likely optimizing at this level).

Comment: @Martin Sure, I did not mean the whole image. But since operations are local, there are no cache misses unless we switch to another pixel. And I assume those switching misses occur approximately with the same frequency.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, let's be clear.  This:

> It is well-known that processor instruction for multiplication takes
>   several times more time than addition

is no longer true in general.  It hasn't been true for many, many years, and needs to stop being repeated.  On most common architectures, integer multiplies are a couple cycles and integer adds are single-cycle; floating-point adds and multiplies tend to have nearly equal timing characteristics (typically around 4-6 cycles latency, with single-cycle throughput).

Now, to your actual question: it varies with both the architecture and the implementation.  On a recent architecture, with a well written math library, simple elementary functions like `exp` and `log` usually require a few tens of cycles (20-50 cycles is a reasonable back-of-the-envelope figure).  With a lower-quality library, you will sometimes see these operations require a few hundred cycles.

For more complicated functions, like `pow`, typical timings range from high tens into the hundreds of cycles.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be concerned about this. If I tell you that a typical C library implementation of transcendental functions tend to take around 10 times a single floating point addition/multiplication (or 50 floating point additions/multiplications), and around 5 times a floating point division, this wouldn't be useful to you.

Indeed, the way your processor schedules memory accesses will interfere badly with any premature optimization you'd do.

If *after profiling* you find that a particular implementation using transcendental functions is too slow, you can contemplate setting up a polynomial interpolation scheme. This will include a table and therefore will incur extra cache issues, so make sure to measure and not guess.

This will likely involve [Chebyshev approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_theory#Chebyshev_approximation). Document yourself about it, this is a particularly useful technique in this kind of domains.

I have been told that compilers are quite bad in optimizing floating point code. You may want to write custom assembly code.

Also, [Intel Performance Primitives](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp/) (if you are on Intel CPU) is something good to own if you are ready to trade off some accuracy for speed.

Answer (score 0):

You could always start a second thread and time the operations. Most elementary operations don't have that much difference in execution time. The big difference is how many times the are executed. The O(n) is generally what you should be thinking about.

Comment: The point is I don't want to implement them, just to estimate the critical section. And I need something more verbose than just asymptotic here.